# String is not adding to itself properly. But is able to compare

Tags: c#, xml, string, loops, tcp

```
string returndata = "";
string FullResponce = "";

bool RecieveAgain = true;

while (RecieveAgain == true)
{
    byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize]; 
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
    returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
    FullResponce += returndata;

    if (FullResponce.Contains("< /Program>"))
    {
        RecieveAgain = false;
    }
    
}

xmlDoc.LoadXml(FullResponce);
```

This is a loop to continue retrieving data until the end xml block (`"< /Program>"`) is contained into the FullResponce of all packets sent combined. When the code is ran, after around 5 loops in my case, the (`"< /Program>"`) is finally contained in the text.

So the if statement runs and finally makes the RecieveAgain = false, thus breaking the loop, so the FullResponce can be loaded into an xml. When it tried to load the xml, it gives me an error that the xml is not complete, and when I check on the FullResponce text, it seems to be missing everything but the first packet (even misses the `"< /Program>"`, which is weird because the if statement in the loop detected it).

Because it is missing half the xml, that is why it gives an error, but why is the Full Responce not adding to itself correctly? The code FullResponce += returndata seems like it only runs once, and that's it.

Also another thing to note, is when I set a breakpoint at the beginning of this loop, and manually go through all the code until it tries to load into the xml, it works perfectly fine, and the FullResponce string is full and complete with all the correct data.

It is like when I have the program run step by step, it is able to add the returndata to the FullResponce properly, but when there is no breakpoint and debugged normally, it gives the error.

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems with it, but the biggest one (and the one causing your issue) is that you are failing to take into account the *actual number of bytes received*. This causes null characters to exist in your string, which are then interpreted by *some* components as the end of the string. (.NET strings are counted, not null-terminated, but there's still lots of code out there that doesn't expect a null character in the middle of a string).

You should change your loop to look more like this:

```
StringBuilder fullResponse = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    string textRead = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    fullResponse.Append(textRead);
}

xmlDoc.LoadXml(fullResponse.ToString());
```

**Note:** in addition to the issue with the null characters, the above version fixes another problem in your original case, which is that you were using string concatenation in a loop. Doing so can lead to serious performance and memory consumption problems; using `StringBuilder` is the appropriate way to concatenate text in a loop.

**Note:** as long as you are *sure* that your XML has only ASCII characters, the above is okay. But note that UTF8 and UTF16 are common these days, XML is technically one of those formats, and there's a lot of XML out there with non-ASCII characters in it. You might want to double-check the XML's encoding and make sure you're using the right one here.

**Note:** in the above code, it uses the end-of-stream indication (i.e. the read operation returns a byte count of 0) to terminate the loop. You definitely should check for this in any case. And `StringBuilder` has no way to check for containment of some specific text, so your previous approach is incompatible with the use of `StringBuilder`.

Now, you may be thinking to yourself "hey, but there might be more data! why not just accept the performance hit and use string concatenation with `Contains()`?". Well, the answer to that is: if it is possible for more data to be present after the end of the XML, then you need a more reliable way of detecting the end of the XML than looking for the close tag.

A `Stream` object has no way to know that it should stop reading your data at the end of the XML, and so the last read operation — the one with the XML's final close tag — can (and probably will) include a portion of the data that follows the XML.

That would mean you'd have two problems:

1. Your XML is polluted with extra data
2. That extra data, which is presumably important to something that occurs later, has already been read and won't be available to the code that needs it.

One way to address this would be to precede the XML in the data stream with a byte count, so that your loop knows how many bytes to read before stopping. Another way might be to convert the XML to binary and then to base64 (possibly compressing the binary first), and then delimiting the base64 data with some character you know isn't valid for base64 data (e.g. a space, newline, tab, etc.).

However you address it, you'll know the end of the XML by some mechanism other than the final close tag of the XML itself, and so can still use `StringBuilder` and won't have to search the string for that close tag.